# Get the player who attended highest number of International or National Game matches?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   SELECT * 
     From (
           SELECT Count(Player_Score_Record.Player_ID) AS TotalC, 
                  Player.First_Name
             FROM Player 
            INNER JOIN (Match INNER JOIN Player_Score_Record 
                        ON Match.Match_ID = Player_Score_Record.Match_ID) 
               ON Player.Player_ID = Player_Score_Record.Player_ID 
            WHERE (Match.M_Type='International' Or Match.M_Type='National')
            GROUP BY Player.First_Name
            ORDER BY Count(Player_Score_Record.Player_ID) DESC
           ) A
    Where A.TotalC = 3 ;
```

I had tried `Max(Count(Player_Score_Record.Player_ID) As TotalC`  – it also shows an error.

The latest try was to use `WHERE A.TotalC = (SELECT Max(TotalC) From A);`. It show

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

So I can only directly assign the number of 3 (max number of matches joined).

Comment: Seeing the table structure would help, I suppose.

Comment: thank you very much , this is my 1st time post question here. i was shock when i was post it a few minutes ago , i was finding the way to do that

Comment: Does your subquery work as expected ?

Comment: You want the max value of totalC. is that it ?

Comment: Given that a player's name is almost assuredly _not_ unique, you're going to want to be grouping by `Player_Id`.  Why are you trying to select a specific number of matches - you have no guarantee that's going to stay the same... but it looks like you should be able to add a `LIMIT` statement in there...

Comment: i was trying to count the number of match  player joined after that i want to use "MAX" function to get the player who had join total of International and national.

(actually have 4 type match international, national, local and friendly match)

Yes i wish to get the max value instance of fix it. This is my assignment. i still have a lot to learn

yes the Player name is not Unique , will be repeated everytime he join the match

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure whether you just want:

- a list of players ordered by number of played matches.
- a list of players that have played as much matches as the player who has played more matches.

Anyway, you can try either of the following solutions. Please take in account these SQL sentences are untested as I have currently no access to a database.

---

If it is option 1 you could use following SQL:

```
select Player.first_name, player_matches.player_id, player_matches.total_played
  from (
        select Player_ID, count(Match_ID) TotalPlayed
          from Player_Score_Record
          join Match
            on Match.Match_ID = Player_Score_Record.Match_ID 
         where (Match.M_Type='International' Or Match.M_Type='National')
         group by Player_ID
      ) player_matches
  join Player on player_matches.player_id = player.player_id
 order by player_matches.total_played desc
```

What we do in this select is:

1. First we get a list of `Player_ID` and the number of matches that player has played.
2. Then we join it with `Player` to get any further data we want.
3. Finally we order it. You might want to filter by `total_played` here.

---

If, on the other hand, it is option 2 that you want try following SQL:

```
select Player.first_name, Player_ID, count(Match_ID) TotalPlayed
  from Player_Score_Record 
  join Player
    on Player_Score_Record.player_id = player.player_id
 group by Player_ID 
 having count(Match_ID) = (
                            select max(total_played)
                              from (
                                     select Player_ID, count(Match_ID) TotalPlayed
                                       from Player_Score_Record
                                       join Match
                                         on Match.Match_ID = Player_Score_Record.Match_ID 
                                      where (Match.M_Type='International' Or Match.M_Type='National')
                                      group by Player_ID
                                   )
```

What we do in this select is:

1. First we get a list of `Player_ID` and the number of matches that player has played.
2. Then we extract the maximum number of played matches by any player.
3. Finally we get the player information of any player that has played that maximum number of matches.

Comment: Thank you very much Guillem Vicens, the option 2 coding is what i want. current it still not working but this give me a great idea of how the coding might works :D

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

- Query 1: if you want all the `Player_ID`s of players with the highest number of games played; or
- Query 2: if you only want a single player with the highest number of games played.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbee5/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Player
(
  Player_ID  PRIMARY KEY,
  First_Name
) AS
          SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'A' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Match
(
  Match_ID PRIMARY KEY,
  M_Type
) AS
          SELECT 1, 'National' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'International' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'League' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Player_Score_Record
(
  Player_ID NUMBER(1),
  Match_ID  NUMBER(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (Player_ID, Match_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Player (Player_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Match_ID) REFERENCES Match (Match_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Player_Score_Record
          SELECT 1,1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH num_games AS (
  SELECT r.Player_ID, COUNT(1) AS number_of_games_played
  FROM   Player_Score_Record r
         INNER JOIN
         Match m
         ON (r.Match_ID = m.Match_ID)
  WHERE  m.M_Type IN ( 'National', 'International' )
  GROUP BY r.Player_ID
)
SELECT Player_ID
FROM   num_games
WHERE  number_of_games_played = (SELECT MAX(number_of_games_played)
                                 FROM   num_games)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbee5/8/0)**:

```
| PLAYER_ID |
|-----------|
|         1 |
|         2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH num_games AS (
  SELECT r.Player_ID, COUNT(1) AS number_of_games_played
  FROM   Player_Score_Record r
         INNER JOIN
         Match m
         ON (r.Match_ID = m.Match_ID)
  WHERE  m.M_Type IN ( 'National', 'International' )
  GROUP BY r.Player_ID
  ORDER BY number_of_games_played DESC, r.Player_ID
)
SELECT Player_ID
FROM   num_games
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbee5/8/1)**:

```
| PLAYER_ID |
|-----------|
|         1 |
```